# Assigning values in a sequence depending on previous row value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have asked a similar question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335527/assigning-values-in-a-sequence-depending-on-previous-row-in-r) and the solution mentioned there works fine with problem stated there but this one is little trickier and harder version of that.

I have a data table like this.

```
   ID1 member
 1   a parent
 2   a  child
 3   a parent
 4   a  child
 5   a  child
 6   b parent
 7   b parent
 8   b  child
 9   c  child
10   c  child
11   c parent
12   c  child
```

And I want to assign a sequence like below keeping in mind **ID1** and **member** column.

```
   ID1 member sequence
 1   a parent        1
 2   a  child        2
 3   a parent        1
 4   a  child        2
 5   a  child        3
 6   b parent        1
 7   b parent        1
 8   b  child        2
 9   c  child        2 *
10   c  child        3
11   c parent        1
12   c  child        2
```

i.e.

```
> dt$sequence = 1, wherever dt$member == "parent"

> dt$sequence = previous_row_value + 1, wherever dt$member=="child"
```

But sometimes it can happen that new ID1 might not start with a member="parent". If it starts with "child" (as in example with star-marked row) we have to start sequencing with 2.
As of now I have been doing it using loops, like below.

```
dt_sequence <- dt[ ,sequencing(.SD), by="ID1"]

sequencing <- function(dt){
  for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){
    if(i == 1){
      if(dt[i,member] %in% "child")
        dt$sequence[i] = 2
      else
        dt$sequence[i] = 1
    }
    else{
      if(dt[i,member] %in% "child")
        dt$sequence[i] = as.numeric(dt$sequence[i-1]) + 1
      else
        dt$sequence[i] = 1
    }
  }
  return(dt)
}
```

I ran this code on a data table of 4e5 rows and it took a lot of time to complete (around 20 mins).
Can anyone suggest a faster way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="   ID1 member
 1   a parent
 2   a  child
 3   a parent
 4   a  child
 5   a  child
 6   b parent
 7   b parent
 8   b  child
 9   c  child
10   c  child
11   c parent
12   c  child", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, sequence := seq_along(member) + (member[1] == "child"), 
   by = list(ID1, cumsum(member == "parent"))]

#    ID1 member sequence
# 1:   a parent        1
# 2:   a  child        2
# 3:   a parent        1
# 4:   a  child        2
# 5:   a  child        3
# 6:   b parent        1
# 7:   b parent        1
# 8:   b  child        2
# 9:   c  child        2
#10:   c  child        3
#11:   c parent        1
#12:   c  child        2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
dt$sequence <- rep(NA, length(dt$member))
for (i in seq_along(dt$member)){
  dt$sequence[i] <- ifelse(dt$member[i]=="parent", 1, 
                           ifelse(dt$ID1[i]==dt$ID1[i-1], dt$sequence[i-1] + 1, 2)
                           )
   }
```

and easier dplyr solution

```
data <- dt %>% 
  group_by(ID1) %>% 
  mutate(
    seq = ifelse(member=="parent", 1, 2),
    sequence = ifelse(seq==1, 1, lag(seq, default = 1) + 1)
  )
```

If each group `ID1` contains at least one `parent`, much easier solution will be arranging the data within group=ID1 so that `parent` always comes on the top:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(ID1) %>%
  arrange(desc(member))
```

Comment: You could also use `lag(seq, default = 1)`

Comment: Didn't know `lag(seq, default = 1)` behaved differently. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nice question indeed. So here's my solution:

**Data**

```
dd <- structure(list(ID1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                                     .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
                     member = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
                                        .Label = c("child", "parent"), 
                                        class = "factor")), 
                     .Names = c("ID1", "member"), 
                     row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
                                   "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

First, set all elements with `parent` to 1:

```
parent <- dd$member == "parent"
dd$sequence <- 0
dd$sequence[parent] <- 1
```

Now, set all `child` elemetns with no parent to 2:

```
dd$sequence <- ave(dd$sequence, dd$ID1, 
                 FUN = function(.) {
                          ret <- .
                          ret[1] <- if (ret[1] == 0) 2 else ret[1]
                          ret}
)
```

Now, we want to get the length of each sequence of `0's` and the position of each `0`:

```
rl <- rle(dd$sequence)
rl.wh <- which(rl$values == 0)
```

Finally, we can generate the sequences:

```
dd$sequence[dd$sequence == 0] <- unlist(mapply(function(x, r) 
    seq(x + 1, length.out = r, by = 1), rl$values[rl.wh - 1], rl$length[rl.wh]))
```