# Assigning values to a group based on previous rows in R

Tags: r

I have a data table like this:

```
  ID Type
  1    I
  1    A
  1    A
  2    I
  2    A
  2    I  
  2    C
  2    I
  2    I
```

I want to add a column Sequence like below:

```
   ID Type Seq
   1    I   1
   1    A   1
   1    A   1
   2    I   1
   2    A   1
   2    I   2
   2    C   2
   2    I   3
   2    I   4
```

The logic is:
Seq = previous_row_for_user_where_I_occurs +1, when Type=I 
Seq = previous occurrence of I for the user, when Type=A or C

So basically, for a given user number all occurrences of I sequentially. If A or C occurs in between, then assign it the value of I that occurs before it. The IDs have been sorted using a date field.

I referred to the below also but it did not help because if "A" occurs twice for a User, the second occurrence is not numbered correctly. 
[Assigning values in a sequence depending on previous row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335527/assigning-values-in-a-sequence-depending-on-previous-row-in-r)

I am using a for loop now which takes hours as I have 10 million rows.

Comment: The `Type` column is missing from the first data table. Also your logic is not clear for subsequent recurrences. Will the count tally with 3,4,... as more multiples appear?

Comment: I made the changes in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

I think `data.table` package is the best option for this problem:

```
> dt[, Seq := cumsum(Type == "I"), by = ID]
> dt
   ID Type Seq
1:  1    I   1
2:  1    A   1
3:  1    A   1
4:  2    I   1
5:  2    A   1
6:  2    I   2
7:  2    C   2
8:  2    I   3
9:  2    I   4
```

Comment: Your solution is only working by coincidence applied to the example. Try adding a third ID. For example, `10: 3   I`

Comment: @PierreLafortune elaborate

Comment: Your solution is resetting the sequence to 0 after each group. But perhaps that is the expected output. OP will clarify if not.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I see, yeah this would go to 0 if the first Type of a new ID was not I. But I also realize he didn't specify what should happen though so I'm curious

Comment: The solution is perfect. If A or C is the first record it should be assigned a Seq number of 0. Thanks for all the help. I will run it with the 10 million record and hopefully this should run much faster.

Comment: It ran is seconds. WOW. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Seq = cumsum(Type=="I"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. dplyr also solves my purpose but takes several seconds to run with large amount of data. On the other hand data.table command runs within blink of the eye.